# Issue using Google Analytics (ga.js) and Universal Analytics (analytics.js) at the same time

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have attempted to find this questions answer on this site and a few others. But it does not appear to be working for myself. The following url shows explainations on how to use GA and UA together.

[How to use both ga.js and analytics.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036884/how-to-use-both-ga-js-and-analytics-js)

I've tried this example, with the same account and property (but separate property of course), I have tried this with different accounts but I am constantly only getting 'real-time' hits from the first analytic that is ran. Ie, if I put UA then GA, UA only reports live hit, and visa versa.

Additionally I am getting a message on the screen saying "More than one Google Analytic's scripts are registered. Please verify your pages and templates. "

Sad part is when I Google this, I get many results, but they are all sites that are showing the same symptom :(

Tia Charles

Comment: can you share the site?

Comment: I know it's been several years since you posted this, but I think you may solve your issue by using a named tracker for the second tracking code implementation. See this article: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your not using the same Tracking ID You need to log them to different web Properties.

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-y']);
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-z', 'yoursite.com');
```

Notices how one has `'UA-xxxxx-y'` and the other is `'UA-xxxxx-z'`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion. I do believe I had 2 different ID's. This is a good catch but did not resolve my issue. I actually dropped it and put it on a back burner but likely will revisit this. That is if google doesn't push UA on is sooner :P